# Why does the binaryw. format behave differently above width 58?

Tags: sas, binary-data

Consider the following program and output:

```
data _null_;
input a;
length b $64;
do i = 1 to 64;
  fmtname = cats('binary',i);
  b = cats(putn(a,fmtname));
  put i= b=;
end;
cards;
1
;
run;
```

Output (SAS 9.1.3, Windows 7 x64):

```
i=1 b=1
i=2 b=01
i=3 b=001
i=4 b=0001
i=5 b=00001
/*Skipped a few very similar lines*/
i=58 b=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
i=59 b=11111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
i=60 b=111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
i=61 b=1111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
i=62 b=11111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
i=63 b=011111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
i=64 b=0011111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Last few lines of output from SAS 9.4 on Linux x64:

```
 i=60 b=000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
 i=61 b=1111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 i=62 b=11111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 i=63 b=011111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 i=64 b=0011111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

This behaviour is rather unexpected, to me at least, and doesn't seem to be documented on the [help page](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/leforinforref/64790/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1b6ugw71lmhnpn1wixijtysezzg.htm). It agrees with the document I found [here](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/275-2011.pdf) for width 64 - standard double precision - but I don't understand why it flips over at width 59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite get the same result - mine switches at 61 - but I believe the answer is the same.

Up to some point - 58, 60, somewhere around there - SAS is showing you the fixed-point integer representation of the number.  Test this with a decimal, like so:

```
data _null_;
a=3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582;
length b $64;
put a= hex4.;
put a= hex8.;
put a= hex16.;
do i = 1 to 64;
  fmtname = cats('binary',i);
  b = cats(putn(a,fmtname));
  put i= b=;
end;
run;
```

And you will get a sort-of-surprising result - you see `000...0011` for most of your rows, up through 60.  The documentation doesn't explicitly mention this, but it does show it in the example (123.45 and 123 are identical in `binary8.`).

Then starting at 61, or 59 for you I'm guessing, you see the actual representation of the number as SAS internally stores it (or, arguably, how Intel internally stores it).

The binary documentation doesn't explain this well, but the [`HEX.`](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/leforinforref/64790/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0ueabv26pr2fwn19uxk2f4bf10y.htm) documentation does explain it pretty clearly in a tip:

> If w< 16, the HEXw. format converts real binary numbers to fixed-point integers before writing them as hexadecimal characters. It also writes negative numbers in two's complement notation, and right aligns digits. If w is 16, HEXw. displays floating-point values in their hexadecimal form.

Binary is doing the same, and on my machine it happens right at the point HEX would also make the change - at 15x4=60.  And `HEX.` shows the same - notice below; `hex4.` and `hex8.` show a different result than `hex16.`.

To be clear, the value shown at `binary64.` is correct, and not any sort of truncation (though 61-63, and in your example 59-60, are left-truncated).

---

I did find a [SAS usage note](http://support.sas.com/kb/4/572.html) regarding this, though it's clearly out of date based on our tests:

> Beginning with SAS® Version 7, the BINARYw. format was changed to be more consistent with the HEXw. format. When the HEXw. format uses a width of 16, (corresponding to 8 bytes of data), it produces a hexadecimal representation of the floating point value. The BINARYw. format changed so that widths of 57-64 produce a binary representation of the floating point value, since widths of 57-64 correspond to 8 bytes of data.

It also contains a suggestion for how to get consistent results for integers, which may be of use.

> BIN_64=PUT(PUT(VALUE,S370FIB8.),$BINARY64.);

`S370FIB8.` is a [format](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000199382.htm) that converts numbers to their fixed integer binary representation, in IBM Mainframe format.  (I.e., it writes the integer in Big-Endian format, which is not what you'd get on an Intel machine.)

Comment: I removed the bit at the end about why the values are "right", in part because my explanation was insufficiently specific, and in part because it's really a separate question.  If you want to know that (why the value of the `binary64` representation, or `001111111111000...`, is correct for 1) please ask another question and I'll put a more detailed answer there.

Comment: Also - particularly if this affected your programming, it's a good idea to put in a TS ticket with SAS about this, so they update the documentation.  SAS documentation is very hit and miss, and it's always helpful to get it updated when you see something missing.

Comment: So, possibly both system- *and* version-dependent behaviour? That's rather out of keeping for SAS. I agree that some better documentation certainly wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @user667489 What version/system of SAS do you use/have?

Comment: I've tried 2 so far - see edits above. I wonder how other version/system combinations behave? I'll have a go at Solaris x64 on Sparc tomorrow :)

Comment: Ah, maybe something changed between 9.1.3 and 9.3 then.  Mine is 9.3 Windows x64.  Solaris is a Unix variant so it should still be little endian (and thus still roughly the same); more interesting would be on a big-endian mainframe...